# extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars not working under iOS 9

Tags: ios, ios9

i got a problem with iOS 9. I have an opaque navigation bar (`translucent = NO, opaque = YES`) and i have set `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = NO`.
It works under iOS 7 & 8 but has no effect under iOS 9:

iOS8

[image: iOS8]

iOS 9

[image: iOS9]

I already tried `edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone` and `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO` but it didn't help whatsoever.

Does anybody have any ideas? Much appreciated.